# How can I give focus to any Control after a Tab has been selected

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a problem .. I have an error list form (works as validation summary screen) that displays validation of controls that require to save data but have no values.
This form opened when validation occurs on controls in another form that has tab control contains all controls that have validation.

The problem is when I double click on Error List form, I need cursor focus on tab control that have this control and focus on the control itself

The result : focus happened on tab control only .. but I need to focus on the control also

Comment: there is a `Focus();` method for a control. Use it!!!

Comment: i use focus method but it doesn't work

Comment: Then use `Select()` method

Comment: try my answer that will select the cell also and places the control also in specified cell. If it is not working in page load then put in grid keyup and down event

Comment: i try to use select() but also not work

Comment: @user3129023: you need to handle the tabpage Enter event.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Control.Focus()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your tab selected event handler.

Comment: i try to use it in selected page Change for tab control .. but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Call `Focus()` to focus on the next control.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :** You need to handle the `Enter` event of the `TabPage` Control to perform the operations when `TabPage` gains the focus.
**Step 2:** You can call `Select()` function on Required control to gain the `Focus`.

Try This: if you want to gain the `Focus` of `TextBox` control in `TabPage2` use this code

```
  tabPage2.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.tabPage2_Enter);
  private void tabPage2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       textBox1.Select();
    }
```

Comment: I tried this code but with event select page change but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think the trick is to set socus on the tab page first, then set focus on the actual control you want to focus on.

What I was seeing is if the tab page was already selected setting focus to the control works fine. However, if the tab was programmatically activated then setting focus on the control alone does not work.

So this works for me reliably:

```
// first select and focus the tab
TabsResult.SelectedTab = tabRequest;
TabsResult.SelectedTab.Focus();

// then focus the control
txtRequestUrl.Focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

I used password Box inside tab item which was focused with following line of codes programmatically using Loaded event.

```
private void pwd7_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((PasswordBox)sender).Focus();
}
```

This might be helpful for anyone encountering similar problem.